# Additional Chars (=0D) when getting emails from GMail using IMAP with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, gmail, imap

I am trying to write an application that goes over a gmail mailbox, reads emails from a certain address and saves them to PDF. The emails themselves are in HTML and not text
After figuring out how to do this with IMAP, I keep seeing "weird" chars imbedded in the email
This is my code:

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
rv, data = M.login(EMAIL, PASS)
rv, data = M.select("INBOX")
rv, data = M.search(None, 'FROM', DEST_EMAIL)
# assume we find the right UID from the search
rv, data = M.fetch(UID, '(RFC822)')
msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
temp = msg.get_payload()[1]
print temp.get_payload
```

I get an HTML that looks like this:

```
<html>=0D\r\n<head>=0D\r\n\t<title></title>=0D\r\n</head>=0D\r\n<body>=0D\r\n<table width=3D"100%">=0D\r\n\t...
```

I have no idea why the =0D is there and how can I safely remove it? (Search and replace doesn't work that well)

Comment: It looks like the content is quoted-printables encoded. Check the content-transfer-encoding.

Comment: This is quoted-printable encoding.  There are literally dozens of questions here on how to decode this.